# How to use performance.memory API in web worker

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I am trying to get heap usage of objects for webworker.

The performance.memory api is providing result like

```
MemoryInfo {
  jsHeapSizeLimit: 793000000,
  usedJSHeapSize: 10000000,
  totalJSHeapSize: 31200000
}
```

But inside web worker when I try to console.log the memory api is undefined. How can i get memory usage of webworker? Is  the performance.memory in main thread(dont know what to call) supposed to retrieve all usages including web worker. I am totally confused

Update Code

```
<<<main.js>>>
worker = new Worker("worker.js")

<<<worker.js>>>
var perfObj = self.performance;
self.onmessage = function(e) {
  initialize();
}

function initialize() {

  _sockHandler= new SockerHandler(socketURL);
}
class SockerHandler{

 constructor(url) {
   var ws = new WebSocket(url);
   ws.onmessage = (event) => {
     console.log("memory = ", perfObj.memory)
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: How about showing how you're using `Performance API` ..? According to MDN, [the API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Functions_and_classes_available_to_workers) is available in web workers. There's also [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance), though.

Comment: Hi, I have updated the post with Update Code. I think performance.measure is not available for workers. 
It mentions [Not all Performance properties and methods are available to Web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/performance). Is there any other way?

Comment: Did you find anything for this? From what I can tell, the performance.memory attribute in the main thread does not report web worker memory usage

Comment: I think this will work now, with new updates